# How to change button props based on breakpoints in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the variant and/or size on a material-ui button for different screen sizes.  For example, use no variant or size="small" below the "sm" breakpoint and variant="outlined" and/or size="large" above "sm".

Normally, I'd make use withStyles and create a style with theme.breakpoints to affect changes by applying the style to the element using className, however, variant and size are props.

After reading [the api](https://material-ui.com/api/button/), scouring the web, and fiddling extensively, I can't seem to figure out any straight-forward way to change the props based on viewport width.

I've thought about creating a "width-detector" and then using some JS logic to change the button element's props accordingly, but that seems just a bit far out as a solution.

So I'm asking here to see if there is an easier solution out there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Material UI Docs:](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#withwidth-)

> Sometimes you might want to change the React rendering tree based on the breakpoint value. We provide a **withWidth()** higher-order component for this use case.

`withWidth` injects a `width` property into your component that gives you access to the current breakpoint value. This allows you to render different props or content based on screen size.

```js
function ResponsiveButton({ width }) {
  // This is equivalent to theme.breakpoints.down("sm")
  const isSmallScreen = /xs|sm/.test(width);
  const buttonProps = {
    variant: isSmallScreen ? "text" : "outlined",
    size: isSmallScreen ? "small" : "large"
  };
  return (
    <Button {...buttonProps} color="primary">
      Responsive Button
    </Button>
  );
}

export default withWidth()(ResponsiveButton);
```

[image: Edit Material-UI Render content based on breakpoint]

Comment: Thanks, Luke.  That is awesome!  I did read that section, but it didn't click until I saw your example.

Comment: Unfortunately, withWidth was deprecated in v5. Any suggestions now?

Comment: withWidth was deprecated in v5 sadly.

Answer (score 31):

The `withWidth` HOC is deprecated per [Material UI Docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#withwidth).

This is the approach that works now, with a combination of `useTheme` and `useMediaQuery`.

**Edit:** `useTheme` is not really required here, since `useMediaQuery` automatically provides that as an argument.

```
// import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
...

function ResponsiveButton() {
  // const theme = useTheme();
  // const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));

  const buttonProps = {
    variant: isSmallScreen ? "text" : "outlined",
    size: isSmallScreen ? "small" : "large"
  };
  return (
    <Button {...buttonProps} color="primary">
      Responsive Button
    </Button>
  );
}

export default ResponsiveButton;
```

Comment: I've done this, but it doesn't seem to rerender as the window resizes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AleksandrMovsesyan
I imported the usetheme hook `import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';`
and then the useMediQuery hook from ` useMediaQuery,
} from '@mui/material';`
inside my component `const theme = useTheme();
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));`
and then finally in my component attribute I used the isSmallScreen variable to change the attributes value `orientation={isSmallScreen ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'}`

Answer (score 8):

This is my implementation

```js
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const ResponsiveButton = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const desktop = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("lg"));
  const tablet = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));
  const mobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("xs"));

  const sizes = () => {
    if (desktop) return "large";
    if (tablet) return "medium";
    if (mobile) return "small";
  };

  return <Button {...props} size={sizes()}/>;
};
export default ResponsiveButton;
```

Comment: Please add some explanations in addition to your code snippet. What are the key benefits of your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To all those who are from 'mui' and not 'material-ui' age, you can create two different components and pass display as an in-line style. Only one will be rendered for a specific screen size.

Refer the example below.

```html
<Typography
  sx={{ display:{sx:'none', sm:'none', md:'block', lg:'block', xl:'block'} }}
>
  This will be rendered only on screens which are medium-sized and above
</Typography>
<Typography
  sx={{ display:{sx:'block', sm:'block', md:'none', lg:'none', xl:'none'} }}
>
  This will be rendered only on screens which are below medium-sized
</Typography>
```

Not sure if you must mention all the sizes inside display. Maybe you can skip lg and xl once you set md to 'block'.